How can I embed html into my Flutterflow project?
I am wanting to integrate a Hubspot chatbot into my web app built on Flutterflow however have not yet managed to do so. I need to paste the below code into the body tag of my index.html file:
<!-- Start of HubSpot Embed Code -->
  <script type="text/javascript" id="hs-script-loader" async defer src="//js-eu1.hs-scripts.com/my_code.js"></script>
<!-- End of HubSpot Embed Code -->

Any help would be appreciated.
I have used the new Flutterflow extension on vs code however we are not yet able to edit this file using this feature.

Also posted on https://community.flutterflow.io/ask-the-community/post/how-can-i-embed-html-into-my-flutterflow-project-W6X9bHd6fzUr5aF


Export Your Project Code :-
In FlutterFlow, export your project by navigating to Settings > Export Code.
Download the code as a ZIP file to your local machine.

Edit the index.html File :-
Unzip the downloaded project.
Navigate to the web directory of your project.
Open the index.html file in a text editor or an IDE like VS Code.
Paste the HubSpot embed code right before the closing  tag.

After adding the code, save the index.html file.
Run flutter build web in your terminal to rebuild the web app with the updated index.html.


